# Get current time in static format regardless locale

Tags: android

How I can get a static date format regardless of device locale, I have the following function to return the current time yet it returns a different format whenever device language is changed

```
public static String getCurrrentTime(){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Locale("en","US"));
    formatter.toLocalizedPattern();
    Date curDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String dateString = formatter.format(curDate);
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: why formatter.toLocalizedPattern() is being used in the code ? also please share which locale you have selected to get the different format.

Comment: formatter.toLocalizedPattern() typos was just trying something forget about it,
I selected Japanese & Arabic both get different results from en_US.